# Search in array, not only unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a simple array containing Dutch city names:

```
var cities = ['Amsterdam', 'Den Haag', 'Den Helder', 'Rotterdam', 'Utrecht', 'Groningen', 'Zoetermeer', 'Zwolle', 'Delft'];
```

My code to search through this array looks like this:

```
elems.searchField.on('keyup', function(e) {
    var index, city, result;
    var currentCity = elems.searchField.val().toLowerCase();
    for (index = 0; index < cities.length; ++index) {
        city = cities[index].toLowerCase();

        if (city.indexOf(currentCity) > -1) {
            result = city;
            console.log(result);
            break;
        }
    }
});

elems.optionsButton.on('click', function(e) {
    if (optionButtonState === 0) {
        elems.consoleItemSecondAndThird.css('display', 'flex');
        optionButtonState = 1;
    } else {
        elems.consoleItemSecondAndThird.hide();
        optionButtonState = 0;
    }
});
```

You can see two cities that start with "Den", these are "Den Haag" and "De Helder". When I type "Den", I need to see them both listed, however, my code only looks up unique values and only shows "Den Haag" when "Den" is inserted for example. How can I make it display all the values that contain the search query?

Comment: You get only one result because your variable 'result' yields only one city. You could instead use it as an array and continue the for loop. like `result.push(city); continue;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the array and inside the filter use **[startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)** function. But be aware that `startsWith` is in ES6

**StartsWith**

```js
var cities = ['Amsterdam', 'Den Haag', 'Den Helder', 'Rotterdam', 'Utrecht', 'Groningen', 'Zoetermeer', 'Zwolle', 'Delft'];

console.log(cities.filter(item => item.startsWith('Den')));
```

To be compatible with old versions of browsers you can use `indexOf()` function to compare `index`.

```js
var cities = ['Amsterdam', 'Den Haag', 'Den Helder', 'Rotterdam', 'Utrecht', 'Groningen', 'Zoetermeer', 'Zwolle', 'Delft'];

console.log(cities.filter(item => item.indexOf('Den') === 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use startsWith and filter; you can lowerCase the values in there too:

```
elems.searchField.on('keyup', function(e) {
    return cities.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.value.toLowerCase())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `item.contain("Den")`

so it will give you any item in which it will finds "den" 
or you can use `item.startswith("Den")` to specify only those items which starts with "den"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also by using **`RegExp`**.

```js
var cities = ['Amsterdam', 'Ajax', 'Den Haag', 'Den Helder', 'Denmark', 'Rotterdam', 'Utrecht', 'Groningen', 'Zoetermeer', 'Zwolle', 'Delft'];

function check(arr, query) {
  console.log(cities.filter(v => v.match(new RegExp('^' + query, 'g'))));
}

check(cities, 'Den');
check(cities, 'A');
```

Comment: @erol_smsr Consider upvoting? (: